# Can I take a feat at level 1 if I use my skill points to meet the prerequisite skill ranks?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, feats, character-creation, skills, feat-qualifications

The feat [Practiced Spellcaster](https://web.archive.org/web/20121107150247/http://www.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/ex/20041105a&page=2) (*Complete Arcane*, p. 82) has a prerequisite of four skill ranks in Spellcraft.

Can I take this feat at 1st level if I use my skill points to get Spellcraft to four ranks? Is there an answer from an official source?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Yes.

The [d20 SRD](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/feats.htm) has this to say about feat prerequisites:

> Some feats have prerequisites. Your character must have the indicated
>   ability score, class feature, feat, skill, base attack bonus, or other
>   quality designated in order to select or use that feat. *A character
>   can gain a feat at the same level at which he or she gains the
>   prerequisite*.

It's perfectly okay to use your first-level skill points to qualify you for this feat.