# Can a creature with hit die get a prestige class without getting a class level?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, prestige-class

Creatures like dragons start with four hit die and those hit die provide them with enough power to classify for several prestige classes. Can such a creature select a prestige class before getting a base class?

Comment: Addressed indirectly in [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/105650/8610), but it seems fine to let this question stand separately.

Comment: Do you mean "Can a creature use its racial HD, skills and feats to qualify for a prestige class"?

Comment: The literal question posed is self-contradictory; obviously, you can't have 1 level in a PrC and 0 levels in classes.  I'm assuming Mindwin's got the intent right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Yes.**  (It's a long post.)

From the "[Improving Monsters](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/improvingMonsters.htm#monstersAndClassLevels)" section of the 3.5 rules:

> The creature’s Hit Dice equal the number of class levels it has plus its racial Hit Dice. A creature’s "monster class" is always a favored class, and the creature never takes XP penalties for having it.

So in that sense, monsters always have a class -- the "monster class" whose features are defined by their type and HD.  This section also says,

> If a creature acquires a character class, it follows the rules for multiclass characters.

And *those* rules say,

> A character may add new classes as he or she progresses in level, thus becoming a multiclass character. The class abilities from a character’s different classes combine to determine a multiclass character’s overall abilities.

One more should do it!  From the Prestige Classes section:

> Prestige classes offer a new form of multiclassing. Unlike the basic classes, characters must meet Requirements before they can take their first level of a prestige class. The rules for level advancement apply to this system, meaning the first step of advancement is always choosing a class. If a character does not meet the Requirements for a prestige class before that first step, that character cannot take the first level of that prestige class.

So breaking all this down, we find that:

1. Monsters HD are exactly the same thing as "levels in a monster class" for rules related to advancing that monster.
2. Prestige classes follow the multiclassing rules, except insofar as they have requirements which must be met before a level in the class can be taken.
3. Taking a class level (in any class, prestige or otherwise) follows the rules for multiclassing as a monster.

So, as long as the monster meets the requirement for the PrC at the time they would choose a new class level, then **yes.**  The rules are 100% explicitly clear.

For additional reference, [this answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/34412/what-is-the-order-of-gaining-a-level) details the process of gaining a level.

Comment: Prestige classes are also different for XP penalties. Those don’t matter for monsters (and shouldn’t matter for anyone else since no one should use those rules), but your point 2 could be read as saying that the requirements are the*only* difference between multicasting base classes and prestige classes. You might want to clarify or reword. +1 either way though.